# Deploying a war outside of a deploy directory in jboss

Tags: java, jboss

Hello: I am trying to deploy a war file outside of a deploy folder in jboss. I changed the context.xml with the following content:

```
<Context docBase="C:\Apps\foo.war" reloadable="true" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" path="/"></Context>
```

The context file is inside jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\ in 5.1.0.GA and jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\ in 4.2.3.GA.

This is what I thought would be the only changes. But is not working. Can someone please tell me what other files do I have to modify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that I had to add the directory location at jboss-service.xml:

```
<attribute name="URLs">deploy/, file:\C:\Apps\foo.war</attribute>
```

This being in windows and jboss.4.2.3.GA and the application was successfully deployed and accessible through http://localhost:8080/foo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For JBoss 5, you need to [add your custom deploy urls to the bootstrap profile service](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/HowtodeploymyapplicationinanexternaldirectoryinJBoss-5).

Be aware, JBoss 5 uses a vfs layer, which will require you to add your custom deploy location to the list of permanent roots in conf/bootstrap/vfs.xml if you want to avoid filling up your disk space with duplicate exploded jars.  In addition, some [versions of the vfs don't properly recognize literal deploy URLs so you may need to use bean injection](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBVFS-118).

Answer (score 2):

In order to deploy web application outside of deploy directory you have to change profile.xml
See bean BootstrapProfileFactory and property applicationURIs.

```
    <property name="applicationURIs">
        <list elementClass="java.net.URI">
            <value>${jboss.server.home.url}deploy</value>
            <value>...directory outside of deploy dir...</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```